# Count unique values and then also count instances of those unique values with criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if it is possible in SQL Server (through SSMS) to count unique values in column `[Track-ID]`. Then I would like to count how many of these unique values fulfil criteria in other columns:

Having 1 in `[Points Assigned]`
Having anything but 0 in `[Playing Time Sequence no_]`

I would like to count both things independently, but only on the unique `[Track-ID]` values.

Is this possible? I have attempted to do it using the query below:

```
SELECT      
    MONTH([Date of Broadcasting]) AS Month
    , COUNT(DISTINCT [Track-ID]) AS Total_unikke
    , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN [Points Assigned] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Points
    , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN [Playing Time Sequence no_] != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)) AS PlayingTimeSequence
FROM [tblGT$Programme Line]
WHERE YEAR([Date of Broadcasting]) = 2020
GROUP BY MONTH([Date of Broadcasting])
```

Comment: I suspect you want `THEN [Track-ID] END` in your `CASE` expression, rather than `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Also, side note, try to avoid object names that require delimit identification. You're far better off using something like camelCase, PascalCase or snake_case (or even a mix).

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I will definitely bring it up, but in this case it is out of my control since the expected result needs these specific names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes . . . you are close but the logic looks like this:

```
SELECT MONTH([Date of Broadcasting]) as Month
       COUNT(Distinct [Track-ID]) as Total_unikke,
       count(distinct case when [Points Assigned] = 1 then [Track-ID] end) as Points
       count(distinct case when [Playing Time Sequence no_] <> 0 then [Track-ID] end) as PlayingTimeSequence
FROM [tblGT$Programme Line]
WHERE YEAR([Date of Broadcasting]) = 2020
GROUP BY MONTH([Date of Broadcasting]);
```

That is, the `CASE` expression needs to return the column you want to count distinctly.

Comment: I see, because then the returned distinct [Track-ID] will be counted. I appreciate the answer and I think I follow then logic, thanks!